# joining a mesh network

Tags: protocols, distributed-computing

I have a design question. I need to create a protocol that allows a node to join a mesh network, so naturally every node needs to agree that the node is part of the network to continue functioning. I've tried to find papers explaining such a protocol, but I'm still stuck. The best I can come up with is that the new node sends a message to every node in the network, and every node forwards that message. When a node has received a message from everyone, it includes the newest node.

Is there a way to achieve the same result with less messages sent? Any ideas or links to papers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a direct example of the group membership problem. I don't not fully remember any specific protocol, I'm sure you can find many such papers by searching. "Reaching agreement on processor group membership in synchronous distributed systems" by Flaviu Cristian is probably the oldest paper on this.

Consensus on the decision of member addition, is a simple approach one can take. Hence in a synchronous system with crash failures I'm sure you can do something better, as consensus only takes O(f+1) rounds for an f-fault tolerant protocol.